# How to get all buttons and labels under splitContainer.Panel2

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, splitcontainer

I want to get the background color of all buttons and labels under splitContainer.Panel2.
When I try it I discover I not success to run on any control (under Panel2)
I try this code:

```
foreach (Control c in ((Control)splitContainer.Panel2).Controls)
{
    if ((c is Button) || (c is Label))
        MessageBox.Show("Name: " + c.Name + "  Back Color: " + c.BackColor);
}
```

How can I get all background colors of all labels and buttons under splitContainer.Panel2 ?

**EDIT:**

1. I have some panels in splitcontainer.Panel2 and the buttons and labels are in the panels.
2. I get only this meesage: "Name: panel_Right  Back Color: Color [Transparent]"

Comment: what didn't worked in the code you show? did you get exception? does .Controls empty?

Comment: So what do you expect of this?

Comment: I think you have a Panel named `panel_Right` in `splitContainer.Panel2`. That may be the only control you have added. rest may me inside `panel_Right`

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: Thank you! Your are right. It was my fault. But I still not success to get all of them because I have some panels in "panel_right"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you get the message probably because you have a panel under your `splitContainer.Panel2` and should do:

```
foreach (Control c in ((Control)splitContainer.Panel2).Controls)
{
    if(c is Panel)
    {
      foreach (Control curr in c.Controls)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Name: " + curr.Name + "  Back Color: " + curr.BackColor);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without `LINQ`, but I want to use `LINQ` here:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(Control c){            
  return new []{c}.Concat(c.Controls.OfType<Control>()
                                    .SelectMany(x => GetControls(x)));
}    
foreach(Control c in GetControls(splitContainer.Panel2).Where(x=>x is Label || x is Button))
   MessageBox.Show("Name: " + c.Name + "  Back Color: " + c.BackColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add a check for `Button` and `Label`. Add this line before `messagebox`:

```
if ((c is Button) || (c is Label))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still not success go get any instance of button or label. I insert this for the code.